# Dynamic dataTable form deletes its array when ajax is used

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have a dynamic dataTable that adds and removes objects.  This works fine when I don't use ajax.  However, when I use ajax, a problem occurs.  Adding values initially is fine.  However, when I start deleting objects, when I delete the last object, the items list gets deleted as well and becomes null.  I am using jsf 2.2 with primefaces.  I'm not sure what's causing this problem. My code is as follows.

item.xhtml

```html
<h:panelGroup id="list">
    <h:dataTable value="#{item.items}" var="object">
        <h:column>
            <!-- Figure out what these facets are or delete them -->
            <f:facet name="keys">Keys</f:facet>
            <p:inputText value="#{object.x}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="Values">
            <f:facet name="values">Values</f:facet>
            <p:inputText value="#{object.y}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{user.removeObject(object)}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
           </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="add" action="#{user.addObject}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

item.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Item implements Serializable{
    public void addObject(){
        Pair<String,String> tempPair = new Pair<String,String>("","");
        items.add(tempPair);
        return;
    }

    public void removeObject(Pair<String,String> i){
        items.remove(i);
        return;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I tried using jsf 2.1 instead, changing my viewAction to preRenderView, and my code works fine.

Comment: Did you try limiting the components rendered by your ajax call? You _shouldn't need_ to rerender the entire parent `<h:form>` just to remove a row from a table.

Comment: I've tried changing the `f:ajax` to `<f:ajax render="dataTableId">`, but although the add works, the delete doesn't.

Comment: What's the scope of the managed bean? Can you show your full managed bean code?

Comment: `facet` example based on your comment. Not sure if you still need. http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_dataTable.html

Comment: Thanks, Andy, for the facet example.
I've edited my code to include the full managed bean code

Answer (score 0):

I think ajax is missing update properties. Try this:

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" update="@form"/>
```

Comment: You can try to replace execute="@form" by process ="@form".

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in jsf 2.2.0.  I replaced javax-faces-2.2.0.jar with javax-faces-2.2.1.jar and the issue disappeared.

Alternatively, another solution is to replace the `<f:ajax>` above with:

`<f:ajax execute="@form" render=":form:list">`

Apparently, the ajax call works fine in jsf 2.2.0 as long as the the whole form is not rendered.

Comment: Welcome to JSF 2.2 hell. I've been fighting with bugs the past few days myself. The 2.2.1 version is it a snapshot ?

Comment: @Andy No, I don't think so. I believe it was released yesterday, actually.
https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.1/

Comment: Great. I was about ready to give up on 2.2. I'll give this one a try thanks.